# How to send multiple email results to my email in single message

Tags: shell-script

I would like the email results to be delivered to my email in a single message. Can you please tell me how can I do it. Here is a copy of my script below. All 3 email matters should come in single message. Is there any way we can do it?

```
if ((($4) < 3000 ))
then
    echo "Memory Utilization is less than 5% free of Total Memory" | mail vamsi.muluguru@gmail.com # first email
    free -m | mail vamsi.muluguru@gmail.com # second email
    ps -eo pid,ppid,rss,vsize,pcpu,pmem,cmd -ww --sort=vsz|cut -c1-130|tac|head | mail -s "Please bounce high consuming jobs on server "  vamsi.muluguru@gmail.com # third email
else 
    exit 0

fi
```

Comment: Can we save the all above 3 email results into text file and can pass the same to my email? would that work? can you please suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subshell, running all three commands and piping the output a single time:

```
if ((($4) < 3000 ))
then
    (
    echo "Memory Utilization is less than 5% free of Total Memory"
    free -m
    ps -eo pid,ppid,rss,vsize,pcpu,pmem,cmd -ww --sort=vsz|cut -c1-130|tac|head
    ) | mail -s "Please bounce high consuming jobs on server" vamsi.muluguru@gmail.com
else
    exit 0
fi
```